# Yii2 - access model from database in 2amigos gallery widget

Tags: database, model, widget, yii2

**Hi.**

Does anyone know how to access model from database in 2amigos gallery widget in order to **display a image stored in local folder using the path stored in database.**

After intall the widget via composer, my view has the code:

```
<?php $items = [
[
    'url' => 'imagens/portfolio/1.jpg',
    'src' => 'imagens/portfolio/thumbs/1.jpg',
    // // 'options' => array('title' => 'Camposanto monumentale (inside)')
],

];?>
<?= dosamigos\gallery\Gallery::widget(['items' => $items]);?>
```

I need to access model from database to display images.
Something like this:

'url' => $model->path_to_photo,

'src' => $model->path_to_foto,

**Many thanks for an answer**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I figured it out after many tries, but here it is how to do it:**

**In Controller, inside action**

```
$query = new Query;
$query->select('foto')
->from('produtos')
->where('id=1');
$command = $query->createCommand();
$data = $command->queryOne();
```

**In view**

```
'url' => implode(" ",$data),
'src' => implode(" ",$data),
```

**Works like a charm :)**